# string html into javascript

Tags: javascript, string, character-encoding

```
var string =  "<input type='radio' value='0' name='" + dataItem.Id + "'id='0' checked='("+ dataItem.Confirmation + "? true : false)' onchange='handleClick(this," +  @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + "," + dataItem.address + "," + dataItem.FirstName + "," + dataItem.LastName + ");>"
```

Hi, i have a little problem with this string in javascript. the error is the JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 22 in (unknown source location)\n\nSCRIPT1006: Expected ')'.  but i don't know. Any idea?

Comment: If you replace your params with `foo` I get this: `<input type='radio' value='0' name='foo'id='0' checked='(foo? true : false)' onchange='handleClick(this,foo,foo,foo,foo);>` with a single quote missing at the end. Also some spaces missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing single quotation `'` at the end of your `onchange` attribute:

```
onchange='handleClick(this," +  @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + "," + dataItem.address + "," + dataItem.FirstName + "," + dataItem.LastName + ");>"
```

Needs to be:

```
onchange='handleClick(this," +  @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + "," + dataItem.address + "," + dataItem.FirstName + "," + dataItem.LastName + ");'>"
```

**EDIT**

My hunch is that you are still getting an error because you are passing 5 parameters to your `handleClick` function. 3 of which are strings but are not in quotations. Please use this line:

```
"<input type='radio' value='0' name='" + dataItem.Id + "'id='0' checked='" + (dataItem.Confirmation ? true : false) + "' onchange='handleClick(this," + @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + ",\"" + dataItem.address + "\",\"" + dataItem.FirstName + "\",\"" + dataItem.LastName + "\");'>"
```

This solution has escape characters around the 3 string parameters so they are passed as strings

Comment: again error.     "<input type='radio' value='0' name='" + dataItem.Id + "'id='0' checked='" + (dataItem.ClientConfirmation ? true : false) + "' onchange='handleClick(this," +  @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + "," + dataItem.address+ "," + dataItem.FirstName + "," + dataItem.LastName + ");'>"

Comment: As you have accepted the answer from @gurvinder372, I thought that they would have the solution to your problem. I would thing that the missing quotation mark would also cause an issue though

Comment: now i have another problem not work the function onchange. thank you

Comment: <input type="radio" value="2" name="1011068" id="2" checked="false" onchange="handleClick(this,8,01.900003_0,Thomas,CADEK);"> this is the html code from page

Comment: What is the error you are getting? From first glance, parameters; 3, 4, & 5 need to be in single quotations as they are strings

Comment: I'm using the template for the column of Kendo UI grid:           
    template: function (dataItem) {
                            return "<input type='radio' value='0' name='" + 
    dataItem.Id + "'id='0' checked='" + (dataItem.Confirmation ? true : false) + "' onchange='handleClick(this," +  @ViewBag.EventAlternateKey + "," + dataItem.address + "," + dataItem.FirstName + "," + dataItem.LastName + ");'>"
                        },

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting in the console? Please review my amended answer. Can you try my solution and output the HTML that is generated in the markup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166543/discussion-between-user2076889-and-wmash).

Answer (score 0):

Your checked value will be

```
checked=' true ? true : false)'
```

You need to unwrap the logic from quotes

```
checked='"+ (dataItem.Confirmation ? true : false) + "'
```